# There is a way to improve the quality of pre-visualization?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, modifiers

in the preview I have this very low quality black pixels, in the example It's much better. There is a way to seepd up the pre-visualitaztion. I have 32 GB of RAM and a i7 9 generation intel...
Here mine:

[image]

Here the example:

[image]

Comment: in the panel on the right, increase the Sampling value for Viewport

Comment: Please use the [built in tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAIo7.jpg) to add images to your posts. Use any image editor or online optimizer if you must resize an image. Information should be immediately visible to those who would answer your question...

Comment: the page don't let me put any image of those, if I could I would, is not my fault, im not retarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the noise in the viewport, you can increase the Viewport Samples, and/or turn on Viewport Denoising (denoising will provide comparable quality, while allowing you to get away with using fewer samples):

[image: Noise]

Comment: thanks bro, did you did the cup of coffe??

Comment: Yeah - it's from when I did the (old) donut tutorial long, long ago

Comment: I have a problem with the glass, do you know why?? I posted new question